# Python script pauses when I disconnect android phone

Tags: android, python, wakelock, nohup

I'm running a python script in the background (using nohup) on the android device (which is rooted ofcourse).

The script gets battery data using dumpsys and writes this out to a file with a timestamp. The script runs fine as long as the phone is connected to my laptop. As soon as I disconnect it, the script pauses. That is, once I reconnect, it starts writing to the file once again. I saw this as there is a gap in the timestamps being written to the file from when I disconnect and reconnect it.

Any ideas what might be causing the script to pause?

Comment: So I think the issue is the cpu going to sleep. If I disconnect the phone but have the screen on, the stats are recorded. It's just when I turn off the screen that it 'pauses'. So my question is, is there any way around using wakelocks? My goal is to record the battery drain normally so having wakelocks would actually skew the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just need to get the wake lock. No other way around it.

So to get the wake lock from my python script, I write a string to

```
/sys/power/wake_lock.
```

This grabs the partial wake lock. Once I'm done, in order to release the wake lock, I write the exact same string to

```
/sys/power/wake_unlock.
```

This fixes the issue as the CPU does not go to sleep.